# How to insert a row in an Azure Storage Table using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell-3.0, azure-table-storage

I was happy to find the New-AzureStorageTable cmdlet, but I haven't figured out how to insert a new row in the table.

I found the following code on the internet, but the CloudTable.Execute seems to fail.

It needs three arguments as described in [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.execute(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.execute%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) but I cannot figure out how to call the method.

Any ideas are appreciated!

```
function InsertRow($table, [String]$partitionKey, [String]$rowKey, [int]$intValue)
{
  $entity = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity" $partitionKey, $rowKey
  $entity.Properties.Add("IntValue", $intValue)
  $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
}

$StorageAccountName = "MyAccountName"
$StorageAccountKey = "MyAccountKey"

$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$table = New-AzureStorageTable test -Context $context

for ($p = 1; $p -le 10; $p++)
{
  for ($r = 1; $r -le 10; $r++)
  {
    InsertRow $table "P$p" "R$r" $r
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested below you have to use Get-AzureStorageTable to check if the table already exists first.

```
$tablename = "test"
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable $tablename -Context $context -ErrorAction Ignore
if ($table -eq $null)
{
    New-AzureStorageTable $tablename -Context $context
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an alternate implementation using Storage Client Library (`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll`) only.

```
#Insert row ... here $table is an object of type CloudTable
function InsertRow($table, [String]$partitionKey, [String]$rowKey, [int]$intValue)
{
  $entity = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity" $partitionKey, $rowKey
  $entity.Properties.Add("IntValue", $intValue)
  $result = $table.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
}


$StorageAccountName = "accountname"
$StorageAccountKey = "accountkey"
$tableName = "MyTable3"

#Create instance of storage credentials object using account name/key
$accountCredentials = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials" $StorageAccountName, $StorageAccountKey

#Create instance of CloudStorageAccount object
$storageAccount = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount" $accountCredentials, $true

#Create table client
$tableClient = $storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient()

#Get a reference to CloudTable object
$table = $tableClient.GetTableReference($tableName)

#Try to create table if it does not exist
$table.CreateIfNotExists()

for ($p = 1; $p -le 10; $p++)
{
  for ($r = 1; $r -le 10; $r++)
  {
    InsertRow $table "P$p" "R$r" $r
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just tried the code above and it works perfectly fine **`if the table does not exist in storage`**. I was able to reproduce the error you're getting if I try to run this script for a table which already exist in storage. I think this is what is happening: When you call `New-AzureStorageTable` to create a table, if the table already exists then it throws an error and returns a `null` value for `$table` variable and then when you try to execute `InsertRow` function using this `null` valued `$table` variable, you get error on `Execute` function. Ideally `New-AzureStorageTable` should not error out if the table already exists.

Comment: Thanks! I did have to add the following to make it work: Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.2\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll"

Comment: And is there a way to make it work using the New-AzureStorageTable?

Comment: Regarding 1st comment: I launched the PowerShell Console using Azure PowerShell Cmdlets shortcut which loaded everything for me so I didn't need to do add this library manually but otherwise yes you would need to do that. Regarding 2nd comment: For some reason I could not find the metadata of the object returned by New-AzureStorageTable. I can certainly give that a try once I know the kind of methods and properties the object exposes.

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.